# Gluings of tetrahedra

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, geometry, graph-theory, triangulation

I am looking for all the possible ways of gluing tetrahedra to form simply connected manifolds with the topology of a sphere.

I am interested in a function $f(n) = N$ that tells me, that $n$ number of tetrahedra can form $N$ unique "Triangulations". It is important that the configurations cannot be closed so at least $1$ free triangle has to be at the end.

As an example,  let a vertex denote a tetrahedron, then the whole picture discusses a $4$-valent graph. For $n=1$ we have $1$ configuration with boundary (number of sticking out indices) $4.$, for $n=2$ we have $1$ configuration with boundary $6$, for $n = 3$ there are $2$ of them : chain with boundary $8$ and triangle with boundary $6$... And so on.

Is  there any closed formula for that?
If there is, i would be also interested in some distribution of the boundaries if there is any.

Comment: It sounds like you want the topology of a ball $B^3$ not a sphere $S^3$ because you are talking about boundary. When you say sphere say $S^d$ or $B^d$ for clarity.

Comment: This is a well-known open problem (already in dimension 3): Even asymptotics are unclear.

Comment: @MoisheKohan maybe is there any approximate solution, a lower or upper bound? Maybe something that says "it's exponential" or something?

Comment: @Kregnach Yes, exponential lower bound and something like $e^{n^2}$ upper bound.

Comment: @MoisheKohan could you please show me a reference to any of those numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dimension 3, the best known (to my knowledge) result is

Eran Nevo and Stedman Wilson, [How many n-vertex triangulations does the 3 -sphere have?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.1641.pdf), 2013.

and the follow-up result in all odd dimensions:

*Nevo, Eran; Santos, Francisco; Wilson, Stedman*, [**Many triangulated odd-dimensional spheres**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00208-015-1232-x), Math. Ann. 364, No. 3-4, 737-762 (2016). [ZBL1351.52013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1351.52013).

In dimension 3, they constructed $\ge 2^{An^2}$ pairwise non-isomorphic triangulations of the 3-dimensional sphere $S^3$ where $n$ is the number of vertices.
It is not hard to get a similar lower bound in terms of the number of tetrahedra. It is also easy to see that there is an upper bound of the form $2^{Bn^2}$.

For the treatment of even-dimensional spheres, see

*Kalai, Gil*, [**Many triangulated spheres**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02187893), Discrete Comput. Geom. 3, No. 1-2, 1-14 (1988). [ZBL0631.52009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0631.52009).

Comment: I found another article by B. Durhuus who is building on the one you cited: doi: 10.1007/s00220-015-2453-2 from 2014, but apparently these are the last works on that question.